# global variable returns undefined when used in a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables

When I define the variable outside of a func, it returns undefined. I couldn't find out the reason why.

```
document.write(myFunc());

var x = 1;
function myFunc() {
    return x;
}
```

### output: undefined

However if I define variable inside the func, it works.

```
document.write(myFunc());

function myFunc() {
    var x = 1;
    return x;
}
```

### output: 1

Comment: You are calling *myFunc* before the value has been assigned to *x*.

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen foul of a common misconception. Variable and function declarations are processed before any code is executed, however assignments occur in sequence in the code. So your code is effectively:

```
// Function declarations are processed first
function myFunc() {
    return x;
}

// Variable declarations are processed next and initialised to undefined
// if not previously declared
var x;

// Code is executed in sequence
document.write(myFunc());

// Assignment happens here (after calling myFunc)
x = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. However, It makes too complicated to assign a value to x = 1 at the end of execution. Wouldn't it be better to assign it when defining the value?

Comment: @BehramBeldagli—yes, of course, I'm just showing the effect of processing your code. If you want it to work, then put the initialiser for *x* at the top so the assignment happens first (or at least before *myFunc* is called).